# Is there a difference between 1 and sqrt(1) in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I am cleaning a legacy SQL script that queries a data warehouse. I do not have `sys` or `dba` privileges on the warehouse tables. One line of the query has struck me as extremely odd. The original author used sqrt(1) in a function instead of just using 1 or removing the, in my uninformed mind, needless statement altogether.

Assuming `column_a` is a number, what is the difference between the following queries?

```
1>  select column_a * 1 from table_1;
2>  select column_a * sqrt(1) from table_1;
3>  select column_a * pow(1, .5) from table_1;
4>  select column_a from table_1;
```

Comment: Is this MySQL or Oracle? What version? When you say number do you mean number or float? The only reason I can see for multiplying by 1 in this situation would be to implicitly convert a character to a number.

Comment: You've tagged this for both Oracle and MySQL.  Which database are you actually using?  What is the data type of `column_a`?  Is it a `number(x,y)`?  Or a `float`?  Or something else?  Is the actual statement in the `select` list or the `where` clause?  Are there other columns involved in the query?  My shot in the dark is that this sort of thing is sometimes done when you want to prevent an index from being used.

Comment: Number not float. I have tried queries in both MYSQL and Oracle and cannot find a difference.

Comment: maybe just an artefact: when he changed the factor from e.g. sqrt(2) to sqrt(1) he didn't realize it could be removed